# Error InvalidIdentityToken in command aws sts assume-role-with-web-identity

Tags: amazon-web-services, gitlab-ci, openid-connect, sts, assume-role

In **.gitlab-ci.yml** file I have the command `aws sts assume-role-with-web-identity` that return this error:
*An error occurred (InvalidIdentityToken) when calling the AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity operation: Issuer must start with https://*

This is deploy script:

```yaml
deploy:
  stage: deploy
  id_tokens:
    GITLAB_OIDC_TOKEN:
      aud: https://git.mydomain.com
  script:
    - STS=($(aws sts assume-role-with-web-identity --role-arn ${ROLE_ARN} --role-session-name "gitlab-${CI_PROJECT_ID}-${CI_PIPELINE_ID}" --web-identity-token $GITLAB_OIDC_TOKEN --query 'Credentials.[AccessKeyId,SecretAccessKey,SessionToken]' --output text))      
    - export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="${STS[0]}"
    - export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="${STS[1]}"
    - export AWS_SESSION_TOKEN="${STS[2]}"
    - aws sts get-caller-identity
  only:
    - main
```

I`m trying to write a gitlab-ci script that assumes AWS Role with web-identity

Comment: `InvalidIdentityToken: Issuer must start with https://` is it because `--web-identity-token $GITLAB_OIDC_TOKEN` is getting the key-value `aud: https://git.mydomain.com` instead of just `https://git.mydomain.com`?

Comment: What is the audience configuration value you used in your OIDC provider in AWS? You must match the `aud` claim accordingly. Usually, this is supposed to be `sts.amazonaws.com`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure you've configured your OIDC Identity provider in AWS accordingly as well as the trust policy of the role you're trying to assume. Your GitLab instance itself must also be configured with a URL (`external_url` in the `gitlab.rb` config file) that begins with `https://` and be accessible from the internet.

> AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity operation: Issuer must start with https://

If you receive this error, it's likely because your GitLab server's `external_url` configuration value is not set correctly or you are not using HTTPS, which is required.

You must also ensure your IAM OIDC Identity Provider is configured correctly, as well as your IAM role, and your pipeline configuration:

First, [configure the OIDC provider](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_providers_create_oidc.html):

- For the provider URL, use your GitLab server's URL for example `https://gitlab.example.com`.
- For the "Audience": Use `sts.amazonaws.com` -- you can use pretty much any value you wish, but you'll need to use the same value for your GitLab ID token's `aud` claim -- GitLab suggests using your GitLab instance URL here (e.g., `https://gitlab.example.com`)

The setup wizard will connect to your GitLab instance to correctly set the public key fingerprint.

---

Second, your IAM role must have a trust policy document that allows the role to be assumed using a web identity under correct conditions. For example, you may make a condition on the `sub` claim matching your repository path.

You will need the ARN of the provider you created in the first step.

```json
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Federated": "arn:aws:iam::AWS_ACCOUNT:oidc-provider/gitlab.example.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
      "Condition": {
        "StringLike": {
          "gitlab.example.com:sub": "project_path:mygroup/myproject:*"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

---

Lastly, configure your pipeline, ensuring `aud` for your ID token is set to the same "Audience" value used in the first step:

```
deploy:
  # ...
  id_tokens:
    GITLAB_OIDC_TOKEN:
      # use the "Audience" value you used in the first step
      aud: sts.amazonaws.com
  script:
    - >
      export $(printf "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=%s AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=%s AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=%s"
      $(aws sts assume-role-with-web-identity
      --role-arn ${ROLE_ARN}
      --role-session-name "GitLabRunner-${CI_PROJECT_ID}-${CI_PIPELINE_ID}"
      --web-identity-token ${GITLAB_OIDC_TOKEN}
      --duration-seconds 3600
      --query 'Credentials.[AccessKeyId,SecretAccessKey,SessionToken]'
      --output text))
    - aws sts get-caller-identity
```

Comment: I'm using docker compose with nginx as a proxy that listens https and calls gitlab as http. In this case, the gitlab external_url must start with 'https//'?

Comment: Thanks @sytech, Resolved at external_url configuration.  This link has configuration example: https://gist.github.com/ryands/ab54fd05507bfbcff850bff771939375

Comment: @EduardoBasílio yes, even if you have a proxy/load-balancer that terminates TLS before reaching the gitlab application, the `external_url` parameter should be the external URL seen by users with the `https://` scheme. The `external_url` config value is used in the OIDC token `iss` field, which AWS requires to be an HTTPS address. You can still configure gitlab to listen and accept traffic the same way you have now, even if the `external_url` uses the `https://` scheme, see: https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/ssl/index.html#configure-a-reverse-proxy-or-load-balancer-ssl-termination